# Stop the wrest of the javascript code when it encounters a error without stopping the entire bot

Tags: javascript, error-handling, discord, discord.js

Hello im running a discord.js bot in version 12 and I want it so if it encounters a error it stops the rest of that command from running without stopping the entire bot it self
this is my current code:

```
        async function startApp () {
            const currentUser = await noblox.setCookie(args.join(" "))
            .catch( (err) => { 
                message.channel.send("Invaild or Expired data")
                }) 
// rest of the program
```

Comment: Does `setCookie()` return a promise?  What error crashes your bot?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do

```js
process.on("uncaughtException", console.error);
```

in the index of your bot. This would log any error without stopping the bot, no matter the error (provided you don't do `process.exit()` somewhere in your bot).